# How to silently install Photoshop via Adobe Creative Cloud

Tags: adobe-photoshop, silent-install, adobe-creative-cloud

I can silently install the Adobe Creative Cloud, but, how do I also silently install Adobe Photoshop?

What I am trying to do is, silently install ACC, and also silently install Photoshop, by passing a command-line switch to the ACC installer, or how other setup installers do it, by passing a `silent.XML` file to the installer with all the necessary information needed.

Comment: Take a look: https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop-elements/kb/photoshop-element-12-silent-install.html